# Write in Google Sheet in a particular folder selected by user

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Currently I have a requirement where I need to provide a pop up (which will be done by Google picker) to the user to select a particular folder . After selecting a particular folder from the pop up a google sheet API will be created in that particular folder.My problem is that I am unable to find out any way to save that selected path in my back end application  so that back end service should pick that selected path and creating a google sheet on that particular path.

Comment: Is the path your users are selecting on the local machine or a folder on Google Drive? Also please provide your current code as your case is quite generic and implementations could be wildly varying.

Comment: User has a provision to select path from google drive and that selected path google sheet should be written. Currently I am unable to findout a way to select that particular path.

Comment: Hi @Rafa,I followed the codebase from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker.

Comment: Please provide ***your*** code.

Comment: I am using google picker that only can select a file. I think that is wrong approached as I need the folder selection pop up for Google drive. I will try to implement it .

Comment: Are you still having issues with this implementation?